# SQLite trigger insert error

Tags: mysql, sqlite, netbeans, triggers

So I have a mysql database the works with this trigger

```
delimiter $$
create trigger update_memberID
after update on memberdata  
for each row
Begin
if not (new.visits <=> old.visits) then
  insert into membervisit (memberID) values (new.memberID);
  end if;
if not (new.memberID <=> old.memberID) then
 update membervisit set memberID = new.memberID where memberID =     old.memberID;
  end if;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Now I am trying to setup the same database on SQLite and everything but this trigger is working. the code I have for the SQLite trigger is

```
"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS `membership.update_memberID` " +
" AFTER UPDATE " +  
" ON memberdata " +
" FOR EACH ROW BEGIN " +       
" SELECT CASE WHEN (new.visits <= old.visits) THEN " +
    " INSERT INTO 'membership.membervisit' ('memberID') values (new.memberID);" +
            "END;\n" +

" SELECT CASE WHEN (new.memberID <= old.memberID) THEN " +
    "UPDATE `membership.membervisit` SET `memberID` = `new.memberID` WHERE `memberID` =`old.memberID`;" +
            "END;" +
"END;"
```

The error I receive is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: near "INSERT": syntax error
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
    at SQLiteSetup.main(SQLiteSetup.java:62)
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The insert it refers to is

```
" INSERT INTO 'membership.membervisit' ('memberID') values (new.memberID);"
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE is an expression; you cannot use it for statements.

But in SQLite, triggers can have a [WHEN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).
(And in SQLite, NULL-safe comparison is IS.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_memberID_visits
AFTER UPDATE OF visits ON memberdata
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.visits IS NOT OLD.visits
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO membervisit(memberID)
    VALUES (NEW.memberID);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_memberID_memberID
AFTER UPDATE OF memberID ON memberdata
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.memberID IS NOT OLD.memberID
BEGIN
    UPDATE membervisit
    SET memberID = NEW.memberID
    WHERE memberID = OLD.memberID;
END;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you. SQLite is a new beast for me I really appreciate it.